# Bad index in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object with bad indexes. I can't edit this, because i application this working ok.

```
var object = { "aaa": 1, "aaa": 2, "aaa" : 3, "aaa" : 4};
$.each(object, function(key, value){

});
```

how can i remove all values where value = 2 and 4?

Comment: if you add the same key, it will overwrite the previous value.

Comment: i want remove values from this object

Comment: @shreedhar no, this working ok :( not overwrite.

Comment: You want to delete the values only or the keys too ?

Comment: your object is of size 1 only.

Comment: @TomMesgert The issue is your example. The object uses the same key 4 times, which is either a syntax error or an overriding key. Is this the actual object from your code? If not and that's just your attempt to generalize it, please adjust it to resolve the confusion it's causing -- `{ "aaa": 1, "bbb": 2, ... }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Every value overwrites the previous one in the literal.

```
$> ({ "aaa": 1, "aaa": 2, "aaa" : 3, "aaa" : 4});
Object
    aaa : 4
$>
```

You will have to ensure that the object literal is well-formed, then use something like this (ES5) :

```
var filteredObject = Object.keys( yourObject ).reduce( function ( target, key ) {
    if ( yourObject[ key ] !== 2 && yourObject[ key ] !== 4 )
        target[ key ] = yourObject[ key ];
    return target;
}, { } );
```

Comment: Nison is correct, your object will always be `Object { aaa=4 }`. See this fiddle to demonstrate the result. http://jsfiddle.net/SUpwM/ `console.log(object);` will show you the object.

Comment: Technically this is a well-formed object literal [as per ECMAScript 3](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-11.html#a-11.1.5).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply do an if(value!=2 && value!=4) into the for?

Comment: Create a new empty object and add the elements from the first to the second only if they match your condition. The $.filter instead is for an array of JQuery objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `delete` keyword to remove the key and that will remove the value

Here is the code

```
var object = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c" : 3, "d" : 4};
$.each(object, function(key, value){
   if(value==2 || value==4){
         delete object[key];
   }
});
```

**Note** : I assumed that the same keys in your example is an error.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all values where `value == 4`:

```
for (var member in object) { if (object[member]==4) {delete object[member]} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `each`.